# Can you use a Jupyter notebook on my GCP VM to run TPU training in Google Cloud?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-tpu

I am switching from running TPUs in colab to running TPUs in Google cloud. I am used to running training in the colab jupyter notebook, but from the GCP TPU quickstart guide, I'll need to use the shell script, and convert my code into a script.

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart

Is there way to open a Jupyter notebook version of my GCP VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you open and run Jupyter notebook on your GCP VM. There must be other ways to do this but here's what I followed and worked for me -

Phase 1 - Make sure you have set up your GCP Project and set up a VM instance in the zone TPUs are supported. For mine, I have used us-central1-f.

Phase 2 - Make sure you have your VM (Compute Engine), Cloud TPU and Cloud Storage are all set and linked according to instructions provided here - https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart

Phase 3 - For VM, you need to enable firewall settings with following

> - Name:
> - Targets: All instances in the network
> - Source IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
> - Protocols and ports: Select “Specified protocols and ports” option.
> - tcp: 8888 
>   Keep other configuration as default.

Phase 4 - You need to install the following:

> - Anaconda

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

> - Tensorflow, Keras and any other libraries you need

```
source ~/.bashrc
pip install tensorflow
pip install keras
```

Phase 5 - Make sure you set up your Jupyter configuration

> 

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
$ nano ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py # I use nano editor
```

> Drop these four lines at the top of this config file and save

```
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

And that's it. You just need to run

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

and hit your browser with http://your_external_IP:8888

Comment: I got to the last part, but the website isn't working.

Comment: I have a feeling there should be a step where my browser connects to gcp somehow

Comment: I found the external IP of my VM, and tried the link, but keep getting This site can’t be reached . I also noticed that the output of the shell gives token ID. I tried that, but got the same result

Comment: works with following this in combo with https://tudip.com/blog-post/run-jupyter-notebook-on-google-cloud-platform/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the helm chart for JupyterHub on GKE, it appears that you can also use a profile for JupyterHub as well.  Make sure to set the correct overrides for kubeSpawner settings:

```
singleuser:
  profileList:
        scheduler_name: default-scheduler
        extra_annotations:
          tf-version.cloud-tpus.google.com: "pytorch-1.11"
        extra_resource_limits:
          cloud-tpus.google.com/v2: 8
```

It's not documented but you'll need to use the "default-scheduler" since GKE will require it to spawn a TPU instances.

Additional documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/kubernetes-engine-setup#job-spec

https://jupyterhub-kubespawner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spawner.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply connect to a VM instance with these flags

```
gcloud compute tpus tpu-vm ssh vm-name --zone provided_zone -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

Next install jupyter and some necessary packages with pip

```
pip3 install jupyterlab
```

Now you can run the jupyter lab with python

```
python3 -m jupyterlab  --allow-root --port=8080
```

Next, you can see the jupyter link in the terminal copy and paste the link in your browser. For further reference visit this [link](https://www.philschmid.de/getting-started-tpu-transformers)